# open one web page with POST data in android

Tags: android, post, android-intent, web

I want open one web page from my app.

I have this code

```
String url = "http://www.mypage.com";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But "http://www.mypage.com" need one POST variable

How can I add one POST parameter?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and you cannot use a webview?

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("var1=1&nextvar2=2", "BASE64");
webview.postUrl(YOUR_URL, post);
```

Comment: and how to get response?